# Refactor java classes on windows file system using cygwin

Tags: sed, refactoring, cygwin

I'm trying to refactor classes from my local working copy due to an urgent refactor needed after a bug fix.
So what i am doing is, using cygwin, move to the dir where my exlipse workspace is located and run this query

```
 find . -name "*.java" -exec sed -i 's/bug/big fix/' {} \;
```

I simply need to replace 1 line of code, 
The issue is, that this affects also classes that does not contain tat bug, i see that by looking at the java files in svn, right after running my command on the java files icons in eclipse it appears the brows asterisk appears, and if i run a diff, i see that all lines differs, even though i thought not even one line should be modified.
My local working copy is on a windows file system, any advise?

Comment: If there are no visible differences, but SVN says that they are changed, then odds are you've ended up with different line terminators.  Is the code supposed to have windows style or linux style line termination?

Comment: From my eclipse configs i see Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Aurand is probably right, it sounds like a line-ending issue.  Reset the repo, then add the `-b` option to `sed` to preserve line endings.